# Vim inserts spaces on save

Tags: macos, vim

Suddenly vim started inserting spaces in the beginning of file when saving using `<leader>w`.

Here I have removed everything from my `.vimrc`:

```
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
```

I press `,w` and the file changes to:

```
     let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
```

Same results both in iTerm2 and Terminal. I am not 100% sure what caused it, maybe I have installed iTerm2 shell integration script, but even after removing it - nothing changed.

`:w` saves normally. Mapping `<leader>r` to `gg=G` adds whitespace to the first line as well. `gg=G` executed via keystroke - re-indents file normally.

What gives? Where to look?

**Update**

Saved a question, restarted vim and it suddenly works fine. Restored full `.vimrc` - adds whitespace again. Removed everything from `.vimrc` except these 3 lines - still adds whitespace on save. Help, I am going crazy.

Comment: do you have `let mapleader = ','`?

Comment: very likely you have autocmd, when save a file, "auto" format the buffer with `gg=G`

Comment: Try using `nnoremap` instead of `nmap`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was stupid, but I had comments after the line which I have omitted in the question:

```
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>      " Fast quit
```

Removing them fixed everything.

Comment: Yeah. Comments don't work on mappings, the map command takes them as part of the mapping.